# Share home directory with host using Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

Is it possible to access files on the guest's home directory from the host?

I'm running a Ubuntu box on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synced folders is what you are looking for:

`config.vm.synced_folder "host/dir", "/guset/home/dir"`

See: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html

Comment: be careful with the _guest's home directory_  if you dont sync with a host folder which contains your ssh key you will not login to ssh, and also think about bash files ....